# Unable to overlap images while stitching them to create panaroma.

Tags: matlab, image-stitching

I am trying to make a panorama with two images (img1 and img2). I got the Homography matrix H. Now I warp the image using:

```
tform = projective2d((H'));

% output size. 
output_dim = [size(img1,1) , size(img2,2) + size(img2,2) , 3];
output_ref = imref2d(output_dim);

% size of panaroma 
img_out = imwarp(img1,tform,'OutputView',output_ref);
```

Now, I want to merge img_out with img2 to get panaroma. I unable to decide how to decide the overlapping position. I tried

```
img_out(1:size(img2,1), 1:size(img2,2),:) = img2;
figure;imshow(img_out)
```

But it doesn't make much sense.Can anyone tell have I correctly chosen output_dim and how should I overlap image? What will happen if I add one more image to it. Thanks